# Why do we sit on saddles that rest on seatposts? (and not on seats that rest on saddleposts)

Tags: saddle, seatpost, terminology, trivia

Why do we call bicycle seats saddles  and why is it a seatpost not a saddlepost? Asking for a friend.

[image: Bicycle parts]

Comment: Well, I call it a "seat".  And those chain-handling thingies are "derailers".

Comment: Silly French words leaking everywhere.   Mech is easier to spell correctly.

Comment: The french word for bicycle seat is "Siège de bicyclette" and saddle is "Selle de vélo" - so I don't think we can blame the french for saddles. Maybe the British? It's a conspiracy from the darn Brooks company?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The question in the title is different to the body.

Comment: I could have put quote marks around the saddle and seatpost in the title but it'd make it hard to read.

Comment: @andy256 They seem identical to me except for what I assume to be a typo (surely should be "sit _on_ saddles").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most things in English language, established convention. According to [Google N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seat+post%2Csaddle+post&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cseat%20post%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bseat%20post%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeat%20Post%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeat%20post%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSEAT%20POST%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaddle%20post%3B%2Cc0), "saddle post" along with "seat post" was used until 1950s, after which "seat post" became dominant.

Comment: What an interesting way to answer the question!  Thanks!